# C# Multiple threads writing to same object seems to run synchronously

Tags: c#

I have about 30 different functions I use to calculate different values. They all go back into the same object. I use Paralell.Invoke, but it seems like the time it takes is still to long.

```
InstrumentStrategy instrumentStrategy = new InstrumentStrategy();

Parallel.Invoke(
() =>
{
///This fills 3 properties in the instrumentstrategy object
instrumentStrategy = RepositoryFactory.GetInstrumentStrategyRepository().SelfCreateSSLCreator(instrumentStrategy);
},
() =>
{
 ///This fills 3 properties in the instrumentstrategy object
instrumentStrategy = RepositoryFactory.GetInstrumentStrategyRepository().SelfCreateCCIcreator(instrumentStrategy);
},
() =>
{
 ///This fills 3 properties in the instrumentstrategy object
instrumentStrategy = RepositoryFactory.GetInstrumentStrategyRepository().HighLowCreator(instrumentStrategy);
},
() =>
{
///This fills 3 properties in the instrumentstrategy object
instrumentStrategy = RepositoryFactory.GetInstrumentStrategyRepository().SelfCreateBollingerValues(instrumentStrategy);
});
```

My thoughts are that the **WHOLE** object is sent into the functions and that memory location might be held, forcing the functions to run synchronously.

Would a **SOLUTION** be to just get the properties and do it more like

```
InstrumentStrategy instrumentStrategy = new InstrumentStrategy();
Parallel.Invoke(
() =>
{
 ///ONLY FILL THE PROPERTY
 instrumentStrategy.SSLValues = RepositoryFactory.GetInstrumentStrategyRepository().SelfCreateSSLCreator(instrumentStrategy);
}, () =>
{
 ///ONLY FILL THE PROPERTY
 instrumentStrategy.CCIValues = RepositoryFactory.GetInstrumentStrategyRepository().SelfCreateSSLCreator(instrumentStrategy);
});
```

Comment: ...what on earth are you doing? ...and **why?**

Comment: _"My thoughts are that the WHOLE object is sent into the functions and that memory location might be held, forcing the functions to run synchronously."_ - this statement makes no sense: `class` objects live in the GC heap, and their references are always passed by value, so objects cannot be "sent into" a function (besides, your use of `=>` is creating thread-unsafe closures, ew) - and even if objects were passed by-value that has no bearing on whether a call runs synchronously or not - and "synchronous" does not mean "not concurrent": it's a separate concept entirely.

Comment: You probably encountered [False sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: @Dai I didn't know that that´s why I was asking here to validate my thoughts.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved! Got the whole process down from well over **500 seconds to about 14 seconds**. As nobody even gave a coding tip or even tried a little to give me a direction to work in. I can just attest to the common feeling that this page is full of a programmers that like to tell people they code can't code or even go as long as just explaining to them that they should be doing something else.

With this I'm closing this question.

Comment: You're correct about this site, but that doesn't mean your question makes any sense.